Import excel data using php
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\symfony\polyfill-mbstring\bootstrap.php on line 136
This is my error.
i'm install composer 2.2.3 and i have php version 7.0.30
no idea becaue im fresher

PHP 7.0.30 is horribly outdated and should not have been in use since years. Also, as you haven't shared any code nor any information about the package versions you use, it's impossible to tell you what exactly needs to be changed. When using Composer properly, it would install packages that are compatible with PHP 7.0.30
